# приложение файла или фото к заказу в woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Как сделать, чтобы к заказу в woocommerce можно было прилагать фото или файл

Comment: а найдутся ли желающие отвечать? вам дали исчерпывающий ответ на предыдущий вопрос. от вас - ни слов благодарности, ни отметки ответа как "принятый"

Comment: да согласен, вы помогли) и ответил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такой плагин - [YITH WooCommerce Uploads](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-additional-uploads/). Он решает вашу задачу.

Comment: сразу спрошу, он платный или нет?

Comment: так пройдите по ссылке, там же можно скачать.

Comment: хорошо. как только я сделаю, сразу отмечу вас